# Javascript: how can I preserve reference to object breaks after reassignment?

Tags: javascript

I struggled with the title to use for this post. So let's dive into code:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3};

function func(val) {
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log(val);
  }, 3000);
}

func(arr);
func(obj);

setTimeout(()=>{
    arr[0] = 9;
  obj.a = 9;
}, 3000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    arr = [9,8,7];
  obj = {a: 9, b: 8, c:7};
}, 3000);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lyquix/obxLa3pe/

The reference to `arr` and `obj` from the setInterval is preserved while I make changes to the elements/properties, but it "breaks" when I assign a new array/object to `arr` and `obj`.

**My question is:** how can I make an assignment like this, essentially replacing all the data of an object, without breaking the reference? Is there a standard function or notation? Or do I need to "wipe out" the array/object first and then repopulate elements/properties?

Something like:

```
while(arr.length) {arr.pop();}
for(let key in obj){delete obj[key];}
```

and then repopulate...

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions.  Do you want to know how to empty an object or an array?

Comment: the value of arr is a reference - do you expect the value behind the refence to change or what do you mean by breaks? Asigment replaces values thus replaces references

Comment: The `setInterval` keeps the original array/object simply because it is inside a method.  And is using the parameter passed in, which is not the same variable as what was used to create that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the box pattern to achieve this.

```
var box = {
  arr: [1,2,3];
  obj: { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 };
};

function log(thing) {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(thing.obj);
  }, 3000);
}

log(box);

box.obj = { a: 9, b: 8, c: 7 };
```

Will log `{ a: 9, b: 8, c: 7 }` in 3s.

Comment: In your example, the boxing is unnecessary because you didn't pass an argument to the logging function.

Comment: This makes sense, and probably is the best approach for my specific problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for the object you can use `assign`:

```
Object.assign(obj, {a: 9, b: 8, c:7});
```

this will overwrite the properties in the existing object. but if `obj` had some property `d`, that would remain untouched.

for the array, you can use `splice`:

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length, ...[9,8,7])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is workable but for my use case it is what I was trying to avoid.